# gwt-test-utils with Lombok

Tags: gwt, lombok, gwt-test-utils

How can one convince **gwt-test-utils** to utilize **Lombok**, so that my @Getter methods do exist when running a GwtSpringTest?

```
22:55:09,153 ERROR GwtTreeLogger:60 - Line 67:
The method getLoginService() is undefined for the type LoginBox
```

LoginBox:

```
@Getter(lazy=true)
private final LoginSvcAsync loginService = loginService();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope that the [GWT Setup instructions](https://projectlombok.org/setup/gwt) can help you here:

> Edit your proj-debug and proj-compile batch scripts to add the
>   following VM arguments:
>
> `java -javaagent:lombok.jar=ECJ (rest of arguments)`

Disclosure: I am a Lombok developer.

Comment: Could you please include the howto in your response so people can see it even if for whatever reason the link became dead...? Cheers and thanks again :)

Comment: What are proj-compile and proj-debug batch scripts. Can I set them in gradle?